# inotifywait endless loop after system startup

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I have a service to check if a src.ods file was changed. When the system is rebooted, it keeps looping. When I update the file it starts to behave correctly (restarts only at file change). How to avoid the loop at system start before file change?

```
while inotifywait -q -m -e close_write /home/admin/data/src.ods; do
  echo $(date -Iseconds) Restarting
done
```

Comment: How is this script started and when? Also, as written this should never get to the `echo` part due to the `-m` switch which prevents `inotifywait` from exiting.

Comment: Script is started as a service in `multi-user` mode. `-m` switch is used to keep notifying subsequent changes, not only the first one. This part seems to work correctly.